# Unordered, fixed-size memory-pool based container with frequent insertion and deletion

Tags: c++, memory-management, pool

I'm looking for a container to store a dynamically growing and shrinking family of objects the size of which I know to come near to but never exceed a given bound. The container need not be ordered, so that I'm happy with any kind of insertion, no matter where it takes place. Moreover, I want all the objects to be stored in a some fixed contiguous memory-pool, but I do not require the memory that is actually occupied at some point in time to be a connected interval in the memory-pool.

Is there any container/allocator in the STL or boost that provides the above?

It seems that a reasonable approach would be to use a linked list with memory taken from a fixed-size memory-pool, but I'd rather use some already existing and well-established implementation for this than trying to do it myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just a sorted `std::vector` with a call to `reserve` before ?

Comment: I think a simple std::vector is everything you need here? You could simply preinitialize the vector using vector.reserve(yoursize) to ensure you preallocate the required memory.

Comment: @Johan, cageman: Won't using std::vector introduce heavy load for moving around the data on insertion and deletion?

Comment: @user412173 I don't know about deletion, but insertion should be cheap if its just a `push_back`. Right?

Comment: @user412173 As soon as you need contiguous memory you'll have to move something when you delete in the middle. This consideration apart, you can choose to insert at the end to speed up insertion or sort to speed up retrieval.

Comment: Johan: No, even though I want everything to be stored inside some fixed contiguous block of memory, the objects themselves need not form a contiguous block.

Answer (score 0):

As you need elements to be contiguous, I think you should go for `std::vector`, calling `reserve` at the beginning.

As I said in comment, as soon as you need contiguous memory you'll have to move something when you delete in the middle and that behavior is already handled by `std::vector`using [remove/erase idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Apart from this, if you use only the vector insertion or the lookup will be costly according to your design:

- Either you always add new element at the end and the lookup of an element will cost you but the insertion will be painless
- Or you sort the vector after every insertion (that will cost) and your lookup will be a lot faster using `std::equal_range`

Otherwise if you can afford an additional `std::unordered_set<std::vector<your_element>::iterator>` with a custom hash/equal you have a fair insertion/lookup ratio by looking up with the `std::unordered_set<>` to find where your element is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Recapping, your requirements are:

1. dynamically growing and shrinking
2. no need to be ordered
3. fixed contiguous memory-pool

With the third requirement you rule out most of the node based containers (such as lists or queues). What you are left with are array-like containers. Specifically [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or even [`std::valarray`/`boost::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)).

But with the first requirement you rule out [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (unless you want to implement some weird looking [`std::array<std::optional<T>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) that mimics the functionality of an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

What you are left with is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which happens to fit requirement number two as well. Of course you can manage the [capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) with [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).